# JavaScript/PowerShell: Compare Two files and Save Results to a Text File

Tags: javascript, powershell

I am using JavaScript to run a PowerShell command in order to compare two files; the results are saved to a text file:

```
function RunPowerShell() { var CommandPS= ' $File1 = Get-Content
"C:\\Test\\test1.txt"; $File2= Get-Content 
"C:\\Test\\test2.txt";Compare-Object $File2 $File1 -PassThru
"C:\\Test\\Results.txt"';

var CmdCommand= 'cmd /c PowerShell '+ CommandPS;
}

RunPowerShell();
```

This code run just fine; however, I have to name my Results.txt file dynamically, based on a variable:

```
var AssignedNumber=1 var
Results='C:\\Test\\Results'+'_'+AssignedNumber+'.txt';
```

If i change the PowerShell code to include the variable ( "-PassThru > Results"), my script is not doing anything (the file listed in "Results" is not created):

```
function RunPowerShell() { var CommandPS= ' $File1 = Get-Content
"C:\\Test\\test1.txt"; $File2= Get-Content 
"C:\\Test\\test2.txt";Compare-Object $File2 $File1 -PassThru >
Results;

var CmdCommand= 'cmd /c PowerShell '+ CommandPS;
   }  
RunPowerShell();
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't know java from quantum physics, but if nothing else couldn't you just rename the output file after PowerShell generates it?

Comment: I tried to update your code formatting. I notice that both your code snippets dont have closing `}`

Comment: "}" have been added. Thanks

Comment: Add four spaces in front of the braces you added. I cannot make a small edit like that.

Comment: In the third snippet, it looks like `Results` isn't being concatenated to `CommandPS`, it's just part of the string literal. If that isn't a typo in the post, try `-PassThru > "' + Results + '"'` (notice the placement of the quotation marks).

Comment: Great! I'll repost that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Results` needs to be concatenated to `CommandPS` in the third snippet. It should look like this:

```
function RunPowerShell() {
    var CommandPS= ' $File1 = Get-Content 
    "C:\\Test\\test1.txt"; $File2= Get-Content 
    "C:\\Test\\test2.txt";Compare-Object $File2 $File1 -PassThru > "' + Results + '";'

    var CmdCommand= 'cmd /c PowerShell '+ CommandPS;
}  
RunPowerShell();
```